# PyQt5 How to addWidget at the specific position?

Tags: pyqt5

I have a vertical layout, that contains one element and a spacer.
When i add widgets to the layout it places below spacer.I'd like to get it on top of a layout.
P.S. to add element, I use this command:

```
frame.vert_layout.addWidget(wid)
```

Comment: use `frame.vert_layout.insertWidget(0, wid)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A box layout also has a `insertWidget()` method that thakes the insert position:

```
insertWidget(...) method of PyQt5.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout instance
    insertWidget(self, int, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment())
```

Use that one instead, i.e:

```
layout.insertWidget(len(layout) - 1, widget_to_add)
```

`len(layout)` can be used to get the number of items in the layout.

Comment: Note: `insertWidget()` is only available for QBoxLayout (QVBoxLayout and QHBoxLayout) and QStackedLayout.

Comment: @musicamante The only other direct subclasses from Qt are QFormLayout (which is desigend to use addRow() and insertRow() (taking position) instead), and QGridLayout (for which addWidget() has overloads taking the position directly). Both don't apply in this case.

Comment: I know, I was only clarifying that since your original phrasing could cause some confusion, but I see you already corrected that.